# Vaadin How to preload file to "new Upload"

Tags: java, sql, vaadin

How I said I have templates that I can apply to my form, sometimes this templates contains files that I have all information about them in one object, so if I instance new item Upload, can I put the references (url) to this new Object without user interaction?
Only applying the template?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: I think you have a major flaw in the design, why do you want to do all that. Just give him the option to download your template - if user downloads, updates it and uploads it back its fair enough, if user fails to upload just make sure you initialize the values of upload data to default and send it across for processing.

Comment: I need to do like as I said because the client wants... So, I get this templates from db and only I need to put the content in my form only with button apply , but sometimes this templates have files that I also need to put to my form... so my question is if I can set Object Upload of Vaadin.

Comment: Can't you fake the uploaded file and on click of which you can trigger a download of that file? Because usually upload is used for uploading the files from Client machine not from the server side.

Comment: No, I can't. But I don't need to download any file from server side, in server side only are information about the file to take from hard disk of client (url where is stored in hard disk, name, extension, bytes), so with this, I need to create new Upload item that contains the path to file only if you apply the template. Then when you submit your form, this go to be stored in db.

Comment: What if the file doesn't exist on the Client side in the stored path? Just in case the user is using multiple computers or multiple users have access to this form/record?

Comment: The file is stored in the server of client, and always if you apply template this file exists in server, don't worry about this, is controlled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65064/discussion-between-goodfighty-and-patton).

Comment: This can not work.  You can not trick the browser into selecting a file for you from the users disk (at least not without abusing serious bugs).  If this would work, you would be able to upload sensitive data unnoticed from the user to the server.  Use a toggle for "default or upload" and provide means for the customer to provide the default.